# Instances and classes syntax

Tags: java, compiler-errors

So... I understand the idea of one main method and then being able to call multiple classes. That we can refer to one directly in order to run different scenarios. AKA use it if it is needed. Static is for one instance while main is overarching
Questions:
1. Where i have placed the bar there is a return; which is used to get me out of this instance. However, it is telling me i need a String. Which makes sense because the method and the output must match?
I have attempted: 
1.to return solely the int value
2.to convert the int to string using-String.valueOf(special);
Where is the error?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Overall{
  public static void main(String[] argc){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
  int containsLowerCase = 0;
  System.out.println(" Please give me a string that has a combination of lower, upper, digits and special characters"); 
    String s1 = input.next();
    System.out.println(s1);
  }
  public static String isSpecial (String input){
   int special = 0;
    int i =0;
    for(i=0;i< input.length(); i++){
      char c = input.charAt(i); 
      if (c=='#' || c=='$' || c== '*' || c== '&')
        special++;
       String.valueOf(special);
    }
    return special;


_________________________________________________________
  ^ ONLY FOCUSING ON UPPER HALF ISSUES ^

  public static String print (String input){
    System.out.println(s1);
  }    
public static  int isDigit (int input){
  int digit = 0;
  for(i=0;i< input.length(); i++){
    char c = imput.charAt(i); 
    if (character.isDigit(s1.charAt(i))){
      isDigit++;
    }
    return isDigit++;
  }
}
public static int isLower (int input){
  int digit = 0;
  for(i=0;i< input.length(); i++){
    char c = imput.carAt(i); 
    if (character.isLowerCase(s1.charAt(i))){

      isLower++;
    }
  }
}
public static int isUpper (int input){
  int digit = 0;
  for(i=0;i< input.length(); i++){
    char c = imput.carAt(i); 
    if (character.isUpperCase(s1.charAt(i))){

      isUpper++;
    }
  }
}






}
```

Answer (score 2):

You return special which is an int, you need to define a new String variable and return that or simply `return String.valueOf(special);`.

You called the String.valueOf(int) which will convert an int to a String but you need to place the return value of that method in a String variable.

Example: `String newStringVariable = String.valueOf(special);`

Answer (score 1):

Return String.valueOf(number)

```
public static String isSpecial (String input){
   int special = 0;
    int i =0;
    for(i=0;i< input.length(); i++){
      char c = input.charAt(i); 
      if (c=='#' || c=='$' || c== '*' || c== '&')
        special++;
    }
    return String.valueOf(special);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to mention all your mistakes, and tell you why it is wrong and what it has ro be like.

First, lets begin with your isSpecial method:
You count the number of times a special character is in your String. Most of its code is right, but I think you wanted return type of int not of String. See, the type you write before the name of the method, in this case String, is what type of Object the method will return. In your method you count the number of times a certain event happens, so you want to return that **number** to later calculate with that or something else.

The return statement has to be in the method body, and when it is reached, the current method takes that value and gives it back to the call of it. Afterwards the method exits, so after a return this method ended and the program continues where you called that method. Take following code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        String testText = "This was written on 2.03.2017";
        int numbers = countNumeric (testText);
        System.out.println ("The text containes "+ numbers +" numbers");
    }

    public static int countNumeric (String text){
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
            if (Character.isDigit (text.charAt (i))
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

When executing this method, java creates a new String, then passes that String to the countNumeric method, where count is incremented by one for each digit character in the String. Then countNumeric returns the count. The program jumps back to the main method and there takes the return value of countNumeric and puts it into the variable numbers, then it prints that.

Also you seem to have a problem using String.valueOf. String.valueOf is a method, which takes a number and converts it to a string. But since you declared special as int, you cannot store a String in it (and maybe want to use it later on). So to convert a number to a String, you have to create a new variable of type String, like in this simple example:

```
int number = 123;
String text = String.valueOf (number);
//do something with text
```

So most of your errors are due to missing returns or wrong return type. Also the reurn in your isDigit method is in the for loop, so it will only look at the first character of the String.

I hope I could help you, and would suggest you to look for a good java step by step tutorial, since you don't seem very familiar with programming.